# How to setup VPN connection from android 13/14 native VPN client to mikrotik routerOS for testing mobile app with backend behind a private network?

Tags: vpn, android, ipsec, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I want to test my mobile app on Android 13 with test backend located in private network. Therefore I need to access this network via VPN tunnel.

Since **L2TP/PPTP** VPN connections are **not supported** on **Android 13** anymore, I am wondering how to setup **secure VPN connection** between **Mikrotik router** and **Android 13** device using **native client** which has only these options:

1. IKEv2/IPSec MSCHAPv2
2. IKEv2/IPSec PSK
3. IKEv2/IPSec RSA

I was unable to find any solution for this problem so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a working solution, however not with **L2TP or PPTP**.

Here you'll find how to setup new **IKEv2 VPN** tunnels to your Mikrotik router.

This solution is not trivial, so you need to be ready to invest some time, and be ready to experiment, and to tweak some settings for your own **Android 13** device to work.

First step is to follow and complete setup as provided here:

https://mikrotikon.pl/vpn-ikev2-na-routerze-mikrotik-dla-systemow-windows-i-android/

It is in Polish lang, but you can easily translate it to any other language with a help of google translate engine.

I can confirm this solution is working with some additional tweaks/notes:

1. In your Android 13 choose VPN client (**IKEv2/IPSec RSA**) and provide data especially including imported certificates. You cannot save configuration without providing IPSec Identifier - any string here will work, but you need to make changes as in point 2 also.
2. In your mikrotik router -> go to IPsec->Identities -> open created identity  and set "Remote ID Type" to ignore
3. Deep understanding of your network infrastructure is needed, meaning you need to know what kind of "Dst. Address" you should put in recently created policy in IPsec->Policies
4. Remember that your firewall rules might be blocking these VPN requests, so be ready to fix them also.

Comment: This is a backup answer.  Some stackoverflow maintainers suggested it is not programming related, therefore I'm posting it here. BTW How come it is not programming related?

Comment: Because configuration of routers is not programming? I understand you wanted the VPN to test an app, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinPecka sure router configuration is not strictly related to programming. However  as developer sometimes I need other tools | solutions to complete my workflow.

Comment: Exactly. And then you need other sites then StackOverflow ;)

Comment: @MartinPecka I'm not going to dispute on this, but on the other hand, it would be nice to have all the proper answers in one place, especially when all these stack... web mods are not so meaningful by name. Do you really know where are you going to place your new question (stackoverflow or superuser) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem till today, and I've got a pretty workaround for your problem.

I had to connect to a VPN, which uses **PPTP** protocol, on my android device (**Android 13**) to test an app.

The solution is that, you ain't connect with your phone to the VPN directly, rather then you enable hotspot from a laptop (in my case), which can establish (can use **PPTP** or other protocols you need) the VPN connection, and use that connection with your android device through Wi-Fi.

The link belove shows how to setup a hotspot which enables VPN share:

[https://protonvpn.com/blog/share-vpn-connection](https://protonvpn.com/blog/share-vpn-connection.)

Comment: Sure I've also used VPN on my router level before.  However I needed to test my application on the go for example testing geolocation services, so using another middleware like laptop was not so precise and convenient....